# find the occurrence of a particular character in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have strings like "Galley1","Galley2","Galley3","Galley4","Galley5","Galley6" upto "Galley20"

i need to check a condition which returns true if the string has number between 1 and 7 both included else return a false
my code is as follows

```
const [cartOptions,setCartOptions]=useState(null);
useEffect(() => {

  if(trolleyName){
    trolleyFinder(trolleyName);
  }
}, [trolleyName])

const trolleyFinder=(trolleyName)=>{
if(trolleyName&&trolleyName.includes("1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5"||"6"||"7")){
  setCartOptions("1")
}
else{
  setCartOptions("2")
}
}
```

here trolleyName is a prop which changes when i click a button and when i close the page i am making the cartOptions as null again.but i am not getting the desired result.
what else could be done

Comment: I would advise you to use a regex instead. Also your syntax of includes is not correct. When checking multiple numbers you should rewrite .includes everytime. That is why it always return false, because he only checks on "1".

Comment: Would be the use of  regex string `Galley[1-7]{1}$`an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
trolleyName.includes("1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5"||"6"||"7")
```

This won't work because the `||` operator evaluates to the [first truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value it comes across, which in this case is `"1"`. So your code is the same as doing `trolleyName.includes("1")`

To check if a string contains a number between a certain range (in this case 1-7) you can use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions), that checks for numbers between `1-7`:

```js
if(trolleyName && /Galley[1-7]$/.test(trolleyName))
```

Here `Galley[1-7]$` means match against the text "Galley" followed by numbers between 1 and 7 inclusive (and then the end of the string `$`).

With that being said, if you have full control over `trolleyName`, I suggest making it an object that contains the number as a separate property. That way you can easily check against this property directly. Furthermore, as [@Wimanicesir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9568358/wimanicesir) suggests, if you end up using an object, you can set the cartOption value, which then means you don't need to worry about your conditional.

Comment: I just want to add that if you make an object, which would be wise indeed, you can also set the correct CartOptions function. This way you don't need to check anymore but just run that function :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Very true :) - That'd simply things even further (I'll make an edit to mention that)

Comment: I have numbers till 11 so 10 and 11 has to be accounted otherwise it gives me wrong results.How to address this?

Comment: @bugsmasher I see, I've updated my answer to handle that case